# What are the build arguments in docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'd like to know how the images are build in docker hub. I configured an autobuild from github, so everytime I push to github, docker hub builds a new image. But I can't find out which arguments are passed to the build command. For example I think it is called with --force-rm because in the log I can see that after each step the intermediate layers are removed. I want to reconstruct the build process on my local system (`Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`) because local my images are build and on docker hub I get following error:

```
Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...

KernelVersion: 4.4.0-93-generic
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2017-08-17T22:50:04.828747906+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.30
Version: 17.06.1-ce
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: 874a737
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.8.3
Starting build of index.docker.io/jabaa/angular-cli:latest...
Step 1/6 : FROM node:9.11.1

 ---> d42348c94e97

Step 2/6 : RUN npm update -g npm@6.0.0

 ---> Running in 8a9a45336c6e

 ---> a5b1c2d5f34d

Removing intermediate container 8a9a45336c6e

Step 3/6 : RUN npm i -g yarn@1.5.1

 ---> Running in e8fe63a39537

/usr/local/bin/yarnpkg -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js

/usr/local/bin/yarn -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js

+ yarn@1.5.1
added 1 package in 2.081s

 ---> ed28e5dc20aa

Removing intermediate container e8fe63a39537

Step 4/6 : RUN yarn global add @angular/cli@1.7.4

 ---> Running in 515c038e900f

[91mcontainer_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"yarn\": executable file not found in $PATH"
[0m
Removing intermediate container 515c038e900f

oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"yarn\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

This is the log on my local system:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  80.38kB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:9.11.1
 ---> aa3e171e4e95
Step 2/6 : RUN ["npm", "update", "-g", "npm@6.0.0"]
 ---> Running in 345f035cc8bf
Removing intermediate container 345f035cc8bf
 ---> f3afe30b0623
Step 3/6 : RUN ["npm", "i", "-g", "yarn@1.5.1"]
 ---> Running in bb196caa2c68
/usr/local/bin/yarnpkg -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/usr/local/bin/yarn -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
+ yarn@1.5.1
added 1 package in 0.647s
Removing intermediate container bb196caa2c68
 ---> e353fc928f6b
Step 4/6 : RUN ["yarn", "global", "add", "@angular/cli@1.7.4"]
 ---> Running in d586a40e6157
yarn global v1.5.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "@angular/cli@1.7.4" with binaries:
      - ng
Done in 26.37s.
Removing intermediate container d586a40e6157
 ---> 663e31095604
Step 5/6 : USER node
 ---> Running in 7585e5fca393
Removing intermediate container 7585e5fca393
 ---> c61d72cc9f00
Step 6/6 : WORKDIR /home/node
Removing intermediate container 936231ce0a8c
 ---> afce371c0911
Successfully built afce371c0911
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:9.11.1

RUN ["npm", "update", "-g", "npm@6.0.0"]
RUN ["npm", "i", "-g", "yarn@1.5.1"]

RUN ["yarn", "global", "add", "@angular/cli@1.7.4"]

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node
```